# Where has "scientific mode" gone in gcalctool 6.2.0?

Tags: 11.10, usability, gcalctool

Ubuntu 11.10 ships  gcalctool 6.2.0 .

In previous versions the calculator has five models: *Basic, Advance, Financial, Programming and Scientific*.

However, in this version there are only *four options* in the menu - I can't find the "Scientific model". Has it been removed, or is it hiding somewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

select

> calculator>look at the Top bar,

check advance Then top bar again

> calculator>preference> Number format >scientific.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I've found that the scientific botton has been intergrated into the advance model